# Making it easier to populate DropDownLists

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, entity-framework-4.1

In my MVC3 application I have a couple of create forms, and they all have one thing in common, and that is a DropDownList for selecting the language.

Two days ago I learnt that it was not a good idea to send whole entities (or list of them) to the Views. It is better to send properties via ViewModels.

So in my ViewModel, to take care of the DropDownList I have the following:

```
// Properties for Language DropDownList
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Language is Required")]
public int SelectedLanguageId { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Languages { get; set; }
```

I am still learning Web Development, and I'm not 100% sure that the above is a good idea, I just copied it from [this tutorial](https://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/view-model-pattern-and-automapper-in-asp-net-mvc-applications).

Then what the tutorial author does is something like this:

```
// GET: Post/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var vm= new NewPostVM();
    var langs = languagesRepository.Languages.ToList();
    vm.Languages = langs.ToSelectListItems(-1);
    if (langs.Count() == 0)
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Language");
    return View("Create", viewModel);
}
```

The thing is I do not have a [ ToSelectListItems ] method to call ! so I am guessing he has put in place some sort of Extention method on his Domain (*plus I have no idea what the negative one is for*).

In any case, how can I populate a repeating (commonly used) DropDownList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so after about an hour in chat with 3nigma, we figured it out. I'll share it with you fellow coders.

I had a Solution with 2 projects. One holding my Domain and the other my MVC3 application. In the Domain project create a folder called [ Extensions ] (make sure you don't spell it Extentions like I did :D) and add a class naming it something related to the Entity in Question. I named mined [ LanguageEntityExtension ]

[image: folder structure]

In there a followed [this tutorial](http://www.pudd.co.uk/External-Blogs/13/Posts/4030), and got my code to look like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.WebPages.Html;
using PostssDomain.Entities;

namespace PostsDomain.Extensions
{
    public static class LanguageEntityExtension
    {
        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItems<T>(this IList<T> langeuageEntities) where T : Language
        {
             return ToSelectListItems((IEnumerator<Language>)langeuageEntities.GetEnumerator());
        }

        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItems(this IEnumerator<Language> langeuageEntities)
        {
            var items = new HashSet<SelectListItem>();

            while (langeuageEntities.MoveNext())
            {
                var item = new SelectListItem();
                var entity = langeuageEntities.Current;

                item.Value = entity.Id.ToString();
                item.Text = entity.Name.ToString();

                items.Add(item);
            }

            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

A couple of things here, make sure you *do not forget* the words [ static ], and also make sure you are referencing (using statement) the library [ System.Web.WebPages.Html; ] and **not** [ System.Web.Mvc; ]. You might have to add a Reference to [ System.Web.WebPages.dll ] manually by right-clicking on References folder and adding it that way.

Now then in my controller, I added the relevant using statement [ using PostsDomain.Extensions; ] and then I was able to do the following:

```
var langs = languagesRepository.Languages.ToList();
vm.Languages = langs.ToSelectListItems();
```

Where as before having the Extension method I was not. So that is that. Then in the View where you are displaying the DropDownListFor, have it in the following format:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedLanguageId, new SelectList(Model.Languages, "value", "text"))
```

Note the "Value" and "Text".

That's it. All is working great.

Thanks once again 3nigma for the help.

Comment: Why do you have any kind of dependency on MVC's `SelectListItem` inside your "domain" project?

Comment: Cause I wanted to make it easy to populate DropDownLists. What do you think would have been a better way ?

Comment: At least moving those extensions out of "domain" project. Domain shouldn't be dependent on MVC App, or even web at all. Otherwise is fine.

Comment: By the way, here: `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedLanguageId, new SelectList(Model.Languages, "value", "text"))` you don't have to create SelectList by youself as your Model.Languages is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` already. `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedLanguageId, Model.Languages)` should work just fine.

Comment: You are so right Vasilio. :( I totally forgot about that. A Domain should not know of MVC's existence. That means I am back where I started. :(

How would you recommend I solve this issue, without messing up my Domain ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var vm= new NewPostVM();
    var langs = languagesRepository.Languages.ToList();
    vm.Languages = langs; //assign the languages list to the model property
    if (langs.Count() == 0)
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Language");
    return View("Create", vm); // pass the model that you have created
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Quick Reply 3nigma. I tried that but I got the error [Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PostsDomain.Entities.Language>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)] So I made a cast like so [vm.Languages = (IEnumerable < System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem >)langs;] but it refused the Cast, and I got another error saying it couldn't cast Language to Html.SelectListItem :(

Comment: ok that is because you must be returning an `Ilist` from your `languages repository`. can you confirm that if you are returning an enumeration then there is no need to do `.ToList`

Comment: try `var langs = languagesRepository.Languages.ToList() As Enumerable` if that doesent resolve the problem then post the code of the property that is returning the languages list

Comment: My repository returns an IQueryable<Language>. So I have changed that line to say [ var langs = languagesRepository.Languages.AsEnumerable(); ] Do I still need to cast anything ? cause I'm still getting a red line under [ vm.Languages = langs; ]

Comment: change your model property as `public Ilist<SelectListItem> Languages { get; set; }` then use `var langs = languagesRepository.Languages.ToList();`

Comment: I just did, but still getting the error [ Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PostsDomain.Entities.Language>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) ]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5958/discussion-between-3nigma-and-ciwan)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can load the `NewPostVM.Languages` this way:

```
var vm = new SelectList(languagesRepository.Languages.ToList(), "idLang", "Name");
```

The first parameter of the `SelectList` constructor just need to be a `IEnumerable` "